# Asus Zenscreen Display Resolution Configuration (macOS SwitchResX)

Tags: mac, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using a 13-inch MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina) and a 15.6-inch Asus Zenscreen MB16ACM as an external screen.
System preferences gives me the following "Scaled Resolutions" for the Asus screen:

| Resolution | Frequency | Aspect Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1920 x 1080** | 60 Hz | **16:9** |
| 1680 x 1050 | 60 Hz | 16:10 |
| 1440 x 900 | 60 Hz | 16:10 |
| 1280 x 1024 | 60 Hz | 5:4 |
| 1280 x 960 | 60 Hz | 4:3 |
| 1280 x 800 | 60 Hz | 16:10 |
| **1280 x 720** | 60 Hz | **16:9** |
| 1024 x 768 | 60 Hz | 4:3 |
| 800 x 600 | 60 Hz | 4:3 |
| 720 x 400 | 70 Hz | 16:9 |
| 640 x 480 | 60 Hz | 4:3 |

The only two usable resolutions are 1920 x 1080 and 1280 x 720. Problem with these are:
1920 x 1080 => super sharp but elements are too small.
1280 x 720 => elements have good size but everything appears blurry.

After some research, I came across a tool called **SwitchResX** which (in theory) should solve my issue.
After switching off my SIP, I tried several custom resolutions including: 3360 x 1890, 2400 x 1350, 1680 x 945 of which none actually showed up in my display settings after rebooting. In SwitchResX-settings it only says in status column "Not active - invalid?".

Can someone recommend SwitchResX-Configurations for the Asus Zenscreen or another 15.6-inch screen?

Answer (score 1):

The display is only capable of a maximum res of 1920x1080 [Full HD]. Nothing higher than that is going to work.
Your choices are tight & small or fuzzy & larger. That's it. You need a retina-type screen to sub-divide from higher resolutions.

Comment: I don't use Apple products but found this that should work: https://www.eizoglobal.com/support/compatibility/dpi_scaling_settings_mac_os_x/index.html The point being use only the native resolution but increment the scaling in order to have bigger icons/fonts. The same is applicable to Windows and any modern desktop Linux distro.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Exactly what I need. Unfortunately, the Asus Zenscreen has not got HiDPI-Settings. If I use windows in a virtual machine I can just go ahead and change scaling to 125% at 1920 x 1080p which works excellent. Unfortunately macOS doesn´t offer the equivalent..

Comment: Mac has never had 'screen zoom' like Windows. tbh, the Windows implementation is awful & relies on a software interpolation that is very uncontrolled, but people apparently just got used to it for non-critical workflows. Apple refused to accept the compromise & poor interpolation that structure entails - preferring to keep their displays as crisp & detailed as possible for graphics/video work. Unfortunately, their current scaling implementation relies on the fact that all current Apple displays are Retina [HiDPI] & there is no compromise for a simple 'HD' display.